# Visual Studio Test Pro 2015 Framework & Template issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

So i just recently updated my visual studio from Visual Studio Pro 2012 to 2015 and i'm having 2 issues.

1. The .NET framework does not show at all. They all show in 2012.
2. I pretty much have no templates available for me to use where in 2012 i did (currently only interested in C#).

[Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETB03.png)

[Visual Studio 2012 (What I want to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhhQu.png)

Info for question 1:

1. I tried uninstalling, installing 2015 again and also tried repairing.
2. Downloading the .NET Dev kit.
3. My C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework does contain the .NETFramework.

Info for question 2:

1. I went to the location of devenv and did the devenv/installvstemplates in the command prompt (as admin).
2. In my Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates folder I have only 3 folders: Extensibility, JavaScript, TypeScript

How can i see the templates and framework again?  I've read a lot of other posts here but none seem to do the job. Im guessing i have to fix the template issue first but i have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your point - "*In my Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates folder I have only 3 folders: Extensibility, JavaScript, TypeScript*", I am assuming, you must have selected custom installation of VS2015.

You will have to repair VS2015 and select default installation type like this-
[image: default install]

This is will give you all C# web and windows templates.

You can also try installing [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f8a7e60-2e6b-4220-b334-26d1e60ec54c)

Comment: Thanks for the response but when i installed my VS, i was never given the option to down load a Default or Custom. Also when I run the repair, it just starts repairing with no option for Default or Custom either.

Comment: I also tried to run the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2015 and it didnt do anything.

Comment: You are using this link - https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ correct?

Comment: At first i wasnt but i've tried that one too and it still doesnt show up.

Comment: Then wait for someone else to give you accurate answer.